# How to create HDR and bloom in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, shaders, special-effects, bloom, hdr

Unity3D's [reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HDR.html) describes the HDR Bloom as:

> Using HDR allows for much more control in post processing. LDR bloom
>   has an unfortunate side effect of blurring many areas of a scene even
>   if their pixel intensity is less than 1.0. By using HDR it is possible
>   to only bloom areas where the intensity is greater than one.

My question is how to achieve it in a `surface shader`? I have tried to output both the `Albedo` and `Emission` greater than 1, but still when I set the Threshold of Bloom equal to or greater than 1, no visible effect can be seen.

The relevant part of shader snippet is:

```
float rim = saturate(dot(normalize(IN.viewDir), o.Normal));
if (rim >= 0.98) {
    o.Emission = 1.5; // or any large value
}
```

Which basically outputs a bright white circle when view angle and normal are at almost same angle, and I want to enhance it with HDR. But outputting a value greater than 1 is not being registered and setting the threshold almost equal to 1 (0.98 or above) creates the Bloom on areas other than the bright white spot, which is not what is needed. I have tried to output extremely large values of `Emission` and have also tried output `Albedo` > 1.

Please tell what I am doing wrong or missing. I think I have not been able to figure out what is the meaning of `pixel intensity` > 1 and what settings does this translate to.

Comment: What version and licence of Unity3D are you using?

Comment: Unity3D 4.1.2 paid version.

Comment: Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/script-BloomAndLensFlares.html) as I'm not sure how to do the shaders part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trial and error and reading the Unity3D documentation again, and some help from the link in the comment by Blue, I have been able to figure this out:

In the shader, if emission is greater than 1, then the camera must have HDR switched on (which I missed). Then one can write in shader like this:

```
float rim = saturate(dot(normalize(IN.viewDir), o.Normal));
if (rim >= 0.98) {
    o.Emission = 1.5; // or any large value
}
```

And set threshold greater than 1, and only the areas with pixel intensity > 1 are picked by Bloom. Also without using custom shaders, in my experiment, the default specular shader can also have pixel intensity > 1, and is also picked up by the HDR.

One last thing, while using HDR on the camera, if Anti Aliasing is switched on, it gives a little warning:

> HDR and Multi-Sampling Anti Aliasing (in Forward Rendering path) is
>   not supported. This camera will render without HDR buffers. Disable
>   Anti Aliasing in Quality settings if you want to use HDR.

And HDR doesn't work. So I switched Anti Aliasing off.

This is what I missed earlier. Now the shader emits > 1 and is easily picked by Gloom.
Here is the effect before enabling HDR on the camera:
[image]
Here is the effect after enabling HDR on the camera:
[image]

In the Bloom (Script), Intensity is 8.96, and Threshold is 1.1
Also to create a slight yellow color in Bloom, Color Threshold is (165, 172, 255).
The car's body and windscreens have a custom shader, and the rims have the Unity's default Specular shader. Bloom with HDR works on both.